# ASP.NET Web Api OAuth возвращает 401 Unauthorized

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Я использую Bearer tokens для авторизации пользователей в Web Api приложении. Токены генерируются, но как только я пытаюсь получить доступ к защищенному методу контроллера, приложение возвращает 401 Unauthorized (Authorization has been denied for this request.)
Cors включен, refresh tokens работают. А доступа к защищенным данным нету. Authorization header есть: Authorization : Bearer XXX_token_XXX

В чем может быть проблема, подскажите? Второй день бьюсь.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с похожей проблемой. Может, у вас остался код ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нужно было поменять местами:

```
app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
OAuthConfig.Configure(app);
```

на:

```
OAuthConfig.Configure(app);
app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);
```